# how to conditionally (value in column) search for substrings in another column in python loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to do a substring search in a string by condition in the second column. I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1 = {'Descr': ["VALVE, PRESSURE", "pump ttf", "Valve, electrical", "Geeku, electrical","VALVE, OVERBOARD, BUTTERFLY"],
        'N_Product': ["VALVE", "PUMP", "VALVE", "GEEKU","VALVE"],
        }
df2 = {'N_Product': ["VALVE", "VALVE","VALVE", "PUMP", "GEEKU"],
        'M_Product': ["PRESSURE", "qwerty","", "", "ELECTRICAL"],
        }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
```

(Step 1) For the first row in df1, the N_Product column is VALVE.

(Step 2) We look for VALVE in the N_Product column of every row of df2 and find 3 matches with the following (N_Product, M_Product) pairs: row 0 has VALVE,PRESSURE; row 1 has VALVE,qwerty; row2 has VALVE,"".

(Step 3) Then you need to check whether any of these pairs (df2 (M_Product)) is contained in Df1 ['Descr'], if it is contained then you need to write N_Product + ":" + M_Product + ";" . For Valve you only need to search for "Pressure", "Electrical" and "", others are not required, for N_Product ('GEEKU') - only 'Electrical' ', etc., depending on which pairs are in the df2 file

```
c = df2['M_Product'].astype(str).to_list()
def matcher(x):
    for i in c:
        if i.lower() in x.lower():
            return i
    else:
        return np.nan
df1['Res'] = df1['Descr'].apply(matcher)
```

but I don't know how to cycle through the values ​​of only the corresponding M_Product for N_Product.

Desired result:

```
df1 = {'Descr': ["VALVE, PRESSURE", "pump ttf", "Valve, electrical", "Geeku, electrical","VALVE, OVERBOARD, BUTTERFLY"],
        'N_Product': ["VALVE", "PUMP", "VALVE", "GEEKU","VALVE"],
        },
'Result': ["VALVE: PRESSURE;", "PUMP", "VALVE;", "GEEKU: ELECTRICAL;","VALVE;"],
        }
```

I would be grateful for any help. If you have any options, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(**UPDATED**)

Based on the updated question, my understanding of what's being asked is this:

- Create a new `Result` column
- If the `N_Product` columns in df1 and df2 for a given row match, then append to the value from the `N_Product` column in df1 the first match in column `M_Product` of df2 of a string found in the given row's `Descr` column in df1 (with an intervening `:` character).
- Otherwise, put `N_Product` from df1 in the `Result` column.
- Also append a `;` character to what is put in `Result`.

Here is a way to do that:

```py
def foo(x):
    descr = x['Descr'].upper()
    match = None
    for mStr in df2['M_Product'].str.upper():
        if mStr in descr:
            match = mStr
            break
    if match is None:
        return x['N_Product'] + ';'
    else:
        return x['N_Product'] + ': ' + match + ';'
mask = df1['N_Product'] == df2['N_Product']
df1.loc[mask, 'Result'] = df1.apply(foo, axis = 1)
df1.loc[~mask, 'Result'] = df1['N_Product'] + ';'
```

Explanation:

- Create a boolean Series `mask` that is True for rows of df1 with `N_Product` matching the corresponding value in df2.
- For rows in df1 where `mask` is True, use `apply` to call `foo` which performs the logic of identifying the first value (if any) in the `M_Product` column of df2 that is found in a given row's `Descr` column and packaging it in a string of the form `N_Product: M_Product;` if found, otherwise just `N_Product;`.
- For rows in df1 where `mask` is False (namely: `~mask`), set the `Result` column to be `N_Product;`.

Input:

```
df1:
                         Descr N_Product
0              VALVE, PRESSURE     VALVE
1                     pump ttf      PUMP
2            Valve, electrical     VALVE
3            Geeku, electrical     GEEKU
4  VALVE, OVERBOARD, BUTTERFLY     VALVE

df2:
  N_Product   M_Product
0     VALVE    PRESSURE
1     VALVE  ELECTRICAL
2     VALVE
3      PUMP
4     GEEKU         MBA
```

Output:

```
                         Descr N_Product              Result
0              VALVE, PRESSURE     VALVE    VALVE: PRESSURE;
1                     pump ttf      PUMP               PUMP;
2            Valve, electrical     VALVE  VALVE: ELECTRICAL;
3            Geeku, electrical     GEEKU              GEEKU;
4  VALVE, OVERBOARD, BUTTERFLY     VALVE              VALVE;
```

**UPDATE #2:**

Here's a solution based on a relaxation of the matching criteria for `N_Product`:

- Create a new `Result` column
- For each row in df1, if the `N_Product` value is found in the `N_Product` column of df2, then append to this value the first match in column `M_Product` of df2 of a string found in the given row's `Descr` column in df1 (with an intervening `:` character).
- Otherwise, put `N_Product` from df1 in the `Result` column.
- Also append a `;` character to what is put in `Result`.

```py
def foo(x):
    descr = x['Descr'].upper()
    match = None
    if x['N_Product'].upper() in list(df2['N_Product']):
        for mStr in df2['M_Product'].str.upper():
            if mStr in descr:
                match = mStr
                break
    if match is None:
        return x['N_Product'] + ';'
    else:
        return x['N_Product'] + ': ' + match + ';'
df1['Result'] = df1.apply(foo, axis = 1)
```

Comment: this is almost what I need, just do not understand why for Valve, electrical in the result column did not pull VALVE, ELECTRICAL?

Comment: There is no 'ELECTRICAL' in the `M_Product` column of df2 in your question. Is this correct?

Comment: I fixed it in the data, but it still doesn't work

Comment: OK, please take a look at my udpated answer.

Comment: In your question, you have written: "you need to compare the values ​​from the N_Product columns from the two dataframes, **if they match, then search for the corresponding values ​​from the M_Product column**". To get the updated result you have provided (specifically "GEEKU: ELECTRICAL;"), we would need to ignore the fact that df1[3, 'N_Product] is "GEEKU" and df2[3, 'N_Product'] is "PUMP". Did I misunderstand? Do you not want to require that `N_Product` columns match in df1 and df2 for a given row in order to compare `M_Product` and `Descr`?

Comment: their positions may differ, for example df1 [3, [N_Product] is "GEEKU" and the corresponding df2 [4, N_Product] is "GEEKU"

Comment: maybe you know how to do it?

Comment: If I've now understood correctly what you have in mind (and I'm not 100% sure that I have ...), you can do what you've asked using the code in **UPDATE #2** in my updated answer.

Comment: @constantstrager the link should be kept in the file df2, df2 [1, 'Valve', 'ELECTRICAL'] - replace "ELECTRICAL" - "qweerty", then the file df1 - ELECTRICAL for Valve should not be pulled, because the file df2 does not have such a pair

Comment: this was the task to map only when there is a corresponding pair ['N_Product'] and ['M_Product'] in the file df2 and ['M_Product'] contained in the corresponding df1 ['Descr']

Comment: I changed the input and output data to clearly show what I meant

Comment: if you have any options, please help

Comment: I'm sorry, but your description is not clear to me. Please map it out in very simple steps to avoid confusion. Please update your question to say something like this: "(Step 1) For the first row in df1, the N_Product column is VALVE. (Step 2) We look for VALVE in the N_Product column of every row of df2 and find 3 matches with the following (N_Product, M_Product) pairs: row 0 has VALVE,PRESSURE; row 1 has VALVE,qwerty; row2 has VALVE,"". (Step 3) We search for these pairs in the Descr column of df1 and find VALVE,PRESSURE; so we use this match in row 1 of our Result column. And so forth ...

Comment: you understood me correctly and described in the comments, I updated my question

Comment: if you have any options, please help

Comment: please, if you have ideas on this, can you share them?

Comment: I looked at your updated question. I'm still confused as to what you are actually trying to do. I would encourage you to try to articulate it more clearly, or, better yet, provide multiple (three to five) different examples (ideally in a table format) showing input (df1 and df2) and desired output.

Comment: I asked a new question and wrote in detail, can you look at that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72316147/you-need-to-map-values-from-another-data-frame-in-2-conditions

Comment: could you understand my question I really hope for your help

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand what your question is asking. Again, I would recommend creating multiple different examples (each completely different from the others) showing sample input and sample output to clarify how you want your algorithm to work. You may find, in creating these examples, that you gain some insight into how to answer your own question. In any case, multiple examples would allow SO users (whether me or others) to better understand and help you.

Comment: I created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72316147/you-need-to-map-values-from-another-data-frame-in-2-conditions?noredirect=1#comment127758321_72316147 where did the screens show and describe in detail, please take a look

Comment: Yes, I saw that. There is still only one example. Can you create at least 3 examples of how you want the input and output to look? I'm just trying to think of a way that you may be able to communicate what you're trying to do more clearly.

Comment: I am adding a picture that visualizes what needs to be done, I hope this will help you understand

Comment: OK, that's helpful. Let me take another look

Comment: Please consider accepting this answer if it was helpful.

Comment: so of course, thanks for the help)